# If filename exists,then add extension at the end of file

Tags: c#, winforms

If file exist in the folder and in the database, how can I add extension at the end of the filename?

For example, if a filename like this exists:

```
JOHN_DENVER_SMITH.pdf
```

the code should rename the 2nd record to `JOHN_DENVER_SMITH_(1).pdf`.

Here's my code:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(oldPath);

if (fileInfo.Exists)
{
    try
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
        }

        fileInfo.MoveTo(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", newPath, firstname.Text + "_" + midlename.Text + "_" + lastname.Text, fileInfo.Extension));
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add description what happens when you code is executed. So we don't have to guess what's wrong.

Comment: That's a number, not an extension. `.pdf` is the extension, available through, eg `FileInfo.Extension`

Answer (score 2):

Validate if the file already exists on the new location. If it does, add a counter value at the end of your file name and try again.
Repeat until the filename doesn't exist.

```cs
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(oldPath);

if (fileInfo.Exists)
{
    try
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
        }
        
        var newFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", newPath, firstname.Text + "_" + midlename.Text + "_" + lastname.Text, fileInfo.Extension);
        var i = 0;
        while (File.Exists(newFileName))
        {
            newFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}_({2}){3}", newPath, firstname.Text + "_" + midlename.Text + "_" + lastname.Text, ++i, fileInfo.Extension);
        }

        fileInfo.MoveTo(newFileName);
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
static string GetFilePath(string path)
{
  // do nothing if file not exists
  if(!File.Exists(path)) return path;
  
  int index = path.LastIndexOf(".");
  var ext = index == -1 ? String.Empty : path.SubString(index);
  var pathNoExt = index == -1 ? path : path.SubString(0, index);
  
  int i = 0;
  string result = null;
  
  // Loop until the file does not exist
  while(File.Exists(result = $"{pathNoExt}({++i}){ext}"));
  return path;
}
```

Usage:

```
fileInfo.MoveTo(GetFilePath($"{newPath}{firstname.Text}_{midlename.Text}_{lastname.Text}{fileInfo.Extension}"));
```

You can replace `string` with `ReadOnlySpan<char>` and `SubString` with `Slice` for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a code to generate the new path like this.

```cs
private string NewPathFor(string oldPath)
{
     var fileInfo = new FileInfo(oldPath);
     var newPath = oldPath;
     for (var i = 0; !fileInfo.Exists; i++)
     {
         newPath = $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileInfo.Name)}_({i}).{fileInfo.Extension}";
         fileInfo = new FileInfo(newPath);
     }
     return newPath;
}
```

And then call it,

```cs
  var oldPath=$"{firstname.Text}_{midlename.Text}_{lastname.Text}.pdf";
  fileInfo.MoveTo(NewPathFor(oldPath));
  dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
```

Answer (score -1):

If Not (IO.File.Exists(fileName & "(" & fileNumber.ToString & ")" & fileExtension) Then
'The file does not exist, do something..
Exit Do
Else
'The file does exist, so increment and try the next one...

Comment: Seem like the correct idea, but it would be better to formulate it as working code.

Comment: should be like that